# Firebase Notification - Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my application I'm using Firebase Messaging and I'm testing to receive notification.
I'm using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) as Rest service to configure the notification's body like:

```
{
"to": "/topics/test",
"priority": "high",
"notification": {
    "title": "Test",
    "body": "New",
    "badge": "0"
},
"data": {
    "foo": "bar"
}
}
```

Certificate is ok. I don't understand how to start programmatically a ViewController looking at the data passed..For example if data contains:

```
"data": {
  "foo": "viewcontroller1"
}
```

I'd like to start ViewController1 when user clicks on the notification.

I can only print data in AppDelegate? How can I use values passed?

This is my AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) ->     Bool {
    FIRApp.configure()

    let notificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

    return true
}

// [START refresh_token]
func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

    let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
    print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()
}

// [START connect_to_fcm]
func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
        }
    }
}

//Receive and handle messages
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // Print message ID.
    print("Value for foo -> \(userInfo["foo"])")


    //start viewcontroller programmatically



}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


}
```

Can someone please explain me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets handle the code in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` First we extract which view controller should we present:

```
let type = userInfo["foo"] as! String

 if type == "viewcontroller1" {

 // here we go to start the view controller


 }
```

You will need to use helping method to find the top most view controller to present on top of it.

```
func getTopViewController()->UIViewController{

    if var topController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
        }
        return topController
        // topController should now be your topmost view controller
    }
    return UIViewController()
}
```

To start a ViewController you should make an identifier for that in Storyboard. lets say its also called : `viewcontroller1` then :

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewcontroller1") as! viewcontroller1
self.getTopViewController().presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Note:** When receiving the notification you'll need to check if the app was in background or it was in app or it was outside the app . For each one has different handling of how and when you'll need to show or present your view controller.

Comment: Thanks you @Aaoli, I need to put all this code in my AppDelegate?

Comment: @Jigen for best practice you'll need to get the user info and create another class to manage notification , so from app delegate you'll need to create post notification and the notification handler class will be listening to it as an observer and then you may handle it there , I'll make for you a sample to handle it after my working hours !

Comment: @Aaoli Thanks you, the example would be very helpful, but in my app I need to populate a tableview so I can develop a method to populate it when viewcontroller load (in the viewDidLoad)

Comment: @Jigen sure I'll help you with that !

Comment: @Aaoli Ok let me try this for now:)

Comment: If I click on the banner notification I obtain this error:

'Value for foo -> Optional(viewController1)
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)'

Comment: @Aaoli now it seems to work, however if you have some free time today or tomorrow show me  the example you told :)

Comment: @Jigen , Download the Demo Here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ub23xjZ4jkWXJucWgySmphMlU/view?usp=sharing, please accept the answer if it works ^_^

Comment: I'm using Firebase but thanks you :) I'm using last three lines of your answer in my app :) Accepted:)

Comment: @Aaoli Yes I do, you're not using firebase as I can see in that project

Comment: @Jigen well , make the configuration as usual , but it will have to go through didReceiveRemoteNotification and its handling ? Do you want me to integrate it too ? My point was to show you how to handle the notification perfectly, and without writing all of that in AppDelegate !

Comment: I just said that your answer is correct, I used that first of all, however your example is welcome :)

Comment: @Jigen Very glad, your welcome anytime :) It will be my pleasure if you need anymore help !